# margin takes space but no background

Tags: html, css, margin

I have tree layers: menu, content and footer.

The content-layer has a white background. When I put another div inside the content-layer with margin:20px it sets the margin but not the white background on the margin-top side. So my text is still positioned to the upper border of my content-layer and there is instead 20px space between the menu and footer that I don't want.

http://jsfiddle.net/Bartimi/Y9kWE/

```
#textfield {
    margin: 20px;
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: change margin to padding :)

Comment: @IgorŠarčević : is this normal behaviour or is that a html/css-flaw ?

Comment: Normal behavior, that I explained in my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this margin and add a padding to #content
You need to change the size of the box too, because the padding
so :

```
#content {
    height: 260px;
    width: 680px;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I shall extend my comment with an explanation

The reason why this happens is because the **collapsing margin** rule.

You can read more about it in the official w3 documentation http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

and in case the link becomes dead:

> 8.3.1 Collapsing margins
>
> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or
>   might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins
>   that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined
>   margin is called a collapsed margin.
>
> Adjoining vertical margins collapse, except:
>
> Margins of the root element's box do not collapse. If the top and
>   bottom margins of an element with clearance are adjoining, its margins
>   collapse with the adjoining margins of following siblings but that
>   resulting margin does not collapse with the bottom margin of the
>   parent block. Horizontal margins never collapse.
>
> Two margins are adjoining if and only if:
>
> both belong to in-flow block-level boxes that participate in the same
>   block formatting context no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and
>   no border separate them (Note that certain zero-height line boxes (see
>   9.4.2) are ignored for this purpose.) both belong to vertically-adjacent box edges, i.e. form one of the following pairs:
>   top margin of a box and top margin of its first in-flow child bottom
>   margin of box and top margin of its next in-flow following sibling
>   bottom margin of a last in-flow child and bottom margin of its parent
>   if the parent has 'auto' computed height top and bottom margins of a
>   box that does not establish a new block formatting context and that
>   has zero computed 'min-height', zero or 'auto' computed 'height', and
>   no in-flow children A collapsed margin is considered adjoining to
>   another margin if any of its component margins is adjoining to that
>   margin.
>
> Note. Adjoining margins can be generated by elements that are not
>   related as siblings or ancestors.
>
> Note the above rules imply that:
>
> Margins between a floated box and any other box do not collapse (not
>   even between a float and its in-flow children). Margins of elements
>   that establish new block formatting contexts (such as floats and
>   elements with 'overflow' other than 'visible') do not collapse with
>   their in-flow children. Margins of absolutely positioned boxes do not
>   collapse (not even with their in-flow children). Margins of
>   inline-block boxes do not collapse (not even with their in-flow
>   children). The bottom margin of an in-flow block-level element always
>   collapses with the top margin of its next in-flow block-level sibling,
>   unless that sibling has clearance. The top margin of an in-flow block
>   element collapses with its first in-flow block-level child's top
>   margin if the element has no top border, no top padding, and the child
>   has no clearance. The bottom margin of an in-flow block box with a
>   'height' of 'auto' and a 'min-height' of zero collapses with its last
>   in-flow block-level child's bottom margin if the box has no bottom
>   padding and no bottom border and the child's bottom margin does not
>   collapse with a top margin that has clearance. A box's own margins
>   collapse if the 'min-height' property is zero, and it has neither top
>   or bottom borders nor top or bottom padding, and it has a 'height' of
>   either 0 or 'auto', and it does not contain a line box, and all of its
>   in-flow children's margins (if any) collapse. When two or more margins
>   collapse, the resulting margin width is the maximum of the collapsing
>   margins' widths. In the case of negative margins, the maximum of the
>   absolute values of the negative adjoining margins is deducted from the
>   maximum of the positive adjoining margins. If there are no positive
>   margins, the maximum of the absolute values of the adjoining margins
>   is deducted from zero.
>
> If the top and bottom margins of a box are adjoining, then it is
>   possible for margins to collapse through it. In this case, the
>   position of the element depends on its relationship with the other
>   elements whose margins are being collapsed.
>
> If the element's margins are collapsed with its parent's top margin,
>   the top border edge of the box is defined to be the same as the
>   parent's. Otherwise, either the element's parent is not taking part in
>   the margin collapsing, or only the parent's bottom margin is involved.
>   The position of the element's top border edge is the same as it would
>   have been if the element had a non-zero bottom border. Note that the
>   positions of elements that have been collapsed through have no effect
>   on the positions of the other elements with whose margins they are
>   being collapsed; the top border edge position is only required for
>   laying out descendants of these elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use thisone ,

Sure it's will work fine

```
#content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 720px;
}
```